# c# reading from a file into an array and adding to listbox

Tags: c#

So this is a part of a university assignment that I am stuck on, I am to create a media player and the code I am currently struggling with should read from a .txt file into an array, and then it should read the track title into a listbox named Lst_genre, my code so far is as follows (I am quite new to the website so let me know if I need to put anything else.)

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string[] readFromfile = File.ReadLines("filepathgoeshere").ToArray();
      ListBox listBox1 = new ListBox();
      // add items 
      Lst_Genre.Items.Add(readFromfile);
      // add to controls 
      Controls.Add(listBox1);
}
```

the format of the text file is as follows

```
2
hip hop // i am wanting this to the textbox
eminem- without me.mp3 // both mp3 files should show in Lst_genre
eminem- lose yourself.mp3
```

The genre name should read into a textbox above also but at the moment I am more concerned with the track names. Would be great if anybody could give some input as I am currently at a loss.

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? What is the value of `readFromFile`?

Comment: Please read [ask]. What are you struggling with and stuck on, exactly? Do you need one list of genres which, when selected, populates the song list?

Comment: At the moment when I run my code, the listbox just displays "string[]array" when I want it to display the text that is meant to be read from the file and a random listbox shows up in the top left corner whereas I want to create this to hold my tracks from other genres on a horizontal scrollbar

Comment: Where do you define Lst_Genre?

Comment: Lst_Genre is the name of the listbox that I set up on my form that I am trying to print the data from the file too, sorry for any miscommunication I am still quite new to programming and it is something that despite enjoying, I struggle with a bit.

Answer (score 3):

You have to extract data first:

```
var readFromFile = File
  .ReadLines("filepathgoeshere")
  .Skip(1)                                                  // Skip title 
  .Select(line => line.Substring(0, line.LastIndexOf(' '))) // get genre (not number) 
  .ToArray();                                               // we want an array
```

Then add all the items: `AddRange`:

```
Lst_Genre.Items.AddRange(readFromfile);
```

**Edit 1**: As far as I can see from the comments

> I have a **textbox** above my **listbox** to hold the genre name and the
>   listbox should hold my track names

We actually have to provide data for *two controls*:

```
var allLines = File
  .ReadAllLines("filepathgoeshere");
```

then

```
// Top Line: genre name
myTextBox.Text = allLines[0]; 

// tracks
Lst_Genre.Items.AddRange(allLines
  .Skip(1)   // Here we skip top line (genre name?)
  .Select(line => line.Substring(0, line.LastIndexOf(' ')))
  .ToArray());
```

**Edit 2**: According to the example provided:

```
var allLines = File
  .ReadAllLines("filepathgoeshere");

// Genre name is the second line (top one is id which we skip)
myTextBox.Text = allLines[1]; 

// in case you want to clear existing control, not creating a new one. 
Lst_Genre.Items.Clear();

// Tracks
Lst_Genre.Items.AddRange(allLines
  .Skip(2)     // Here we skip tow lines (id and genre name)
  .ToArray());
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, the information is being read from the file, however on this line `code`(line => line.Substring(0, line.LastIndexOf("Other")))  I am being hit with length cannot be less than 0

Comment: @George taylor: Sorry? I'm trying to get rid of the `id` part which I expect to be after the *last space*, e.g. `"track #12 123"` `"track #12"`. If I've got the format wrong, please *provide examples

Comment: So the part that I called id is the genre number, I have this as I will have to do the same thing with a few files and this is how the txt files have been given to us, I have a textbox above my listbox to hold the genre name and the listbox should hold my track names, using a horizontal scrollbar when in run time my program is meant to move onto another listbox where the other files will be read in. I apologise for the lengthy description :p

Comment: @George taylor: Could you please, provide the initial line (*example*), and the desired outcome? E.g. `"track #12 123"` -> `"track #12"`?

Comment: so at runtime it should look like this (genre name here(genreTextbox)) below that is my listbox named Lst_Genre and I need to display track1 -> track 2 here

Comment: @George taylor: It's an *example* of the file's content I badly need. You have `"Jazz 5" / "Track 1 5" / "Track 2 5"` and you want `"Jazz"` in the TextBox; `"Track 1"`, `"Track 2"` are in the ListBox? Am I correct?

Comment: @George taylor: I see; so `"hip hop"` should be put to the *TextBox*, and `"eminem- without me.mp3"` as well as `"eminem- lose yourself.mp3"` should be items of the TistBox?

Comment: Thats worked! So with the code given, if I did the same with another file would it work the same and display the other file with the same format in the listbox when I click the horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: @George taylor: It should work with any file providing that the format is the same.

Comment: format is the exact same, I am very new, would I have to create a new listbox to display another file, I want it in runtime to be in the same place, and when i click the horizontal scrollbar that is on my listbox I am hoping that the other files content is displayed the same as before

Comment: @George taylor: I doubt if you should create any control manually. I suggest *clearing* exitsing `TextBox` and `ListBox`: `Lst_Genre.Items.Clear();` when you select a file - clear existing controls (which you can create with a help of designer) and fill them with data rom file

Comment: I am trying to make it so that when I press the button on the scroll bar, it switches so that text is shown from another file, I am using about 4 files all with the same format as above but I need it to function with the scrollbar somehow

Comment: If you have the files in a `ListBox` (`ComboBox` etc.) you, probably, should use `SelectedIndexChanged` / `SelectedValueChanged` event

Comment: So am I right in saying it would be the exact same code but just in a selectedindexchanged event handler?

Comment: @George taylor: looks like this. I can't see your code, that's why I have to guess. Usually, we have file names in a kind of list (e.g. in a `ListBox`)  and we have to reload the file when the selection has been changed.